# libravatar support?

Tags: support, feature-request, gravatar

Is there any way to use gravatar alternatives like [libravatar](https://www.libravatar.org)?

Or is it planned?

I've tried searching for "libravatar" in [osqa feature requests](http://jira.osqa.net/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa) without success.

**Edit** : Nothing is wrong with gravatar. I just like libravatar for the same reasons I like stackexchange : Source code is free and available.

**Edit 2** : I've always thought stackexchange was based on osqa, but appently, it's not the case : [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

Comment: What's "wrong" with Gravatar? I feel out of the loop.

Comment: The source code for StackExchange is free and available?

Comment: If you find a "free" copy of the Stack Exchange source code I'm sure the owners would like to know where it is, so they can take appropriate action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about osqa or libravatar but the recent [stackexchange podcas](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/podcast-39-the-one-with-wil-wheaton/)t suggested that there are planned changes relvant to avatars. This has been [confirmed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161083/147520) by [Jeremy Tunnell](http://stackexchange.com/users/1635441/jeremy-tunnell). It looks like SE plans to host user avatars themselves as well as continuing to support gravatars.

Comment: I wonder if rolled out "in a couple of weeks" means *really* a couple of weeks or if it'll turn out to be a few months like the data.SE changes took.

Comment: @Ward you should ask that on meta.stackoverflow.com <ducks flying shoe>